# Queue/thread not affecting main process

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I'm trying to utilize threading and queueing (based on a recommendation) to pause the main process.

My program basically iterates through images, opening and closing them utilizing a 3-second time-loop for each iteration.
I'm trying to use threading to interject a time.sleep(20) if a certain condition is met (x == True).  The condition is being met (evident by the output of the print statement), but time.sleep(20) is not affecting the main process.
I plan to subsitute time.sleep(20) with a more complex process but for simpliclity I've used it here.

```
import time
import subprocess
import pickle
import keyboard
import threading
from threading import Thread
import multiprocessing
import queue
import time

with open('C:\\Users\Moondra\\Bioteck.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    bio = pickle.load(file)





q = queue.LifoQueue(0)


def keyboard_press():    # This is just receiving boolean values based on key presses
    while True:
        q.put(keyboard.is_pressed('down'))
        x = q.get()
        print(x)
        if x == True:
           time.sleep(20)



t = Thread(target = keyboard_press, args= ())
t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in bio[:5]:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe",'C:\\Users\Moondra\\Bioteck_charts\{}.png'.format(i)])

        time.sleep(3)
        p.kill()
```

So why isn't my thread affecting my main process?

Thank you.

Update:

So It seems I have to use flags and use flag as a global variable within my function. I would like to avoid using `global` but it's not working without globalizing `flag` within my function.

Second, I don't know how to restart the thread.
Once the thread returns the `flag` as false, the thread sort of just stalls. 
I tried  starting the thread again, with `t.start`, but I received the error:
`RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`

Here is updated code:

```
def keyboard_press():
    while True:
        global flag
        q.put(keyboard.is_pressed('down'))
        x = q.get()
        print(x)
        if x == True:
           flag = False
           #print('keyboard_flag is',flag)
           return  flag





if __name__ == "__main__":
    flag = True
    q = queue.LifoQueue(0)
    t = Thread(target = keyboard_press, args= ())
    t.start()


    for i in bio[:5]:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe",'C:\\Users\Moondra\\Bioteck_charts\{}.png'.format(i)])
        time.sleep(3)
        print ('flag is',flag)
        if flag == True:

            p.kill()

        else:
            time.sleep(20)
            p.kill()
            flag = True
            #t.start()  #doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: Your `keyboard_press()` function runs in its own thread, polling the keyboard, and sometimes sleeping.  Why do you expect that to have any influence on the main thread?

Comment: I'm trying to influence the main thread if a certain key is pressed anytime during the loop. 
Someone had recommended using threads and queueing as a separate process, so I was attempting to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why isn't my thread affecting my main process?

Because you have not written any code to be executed by the `keyboard_press()` thread that would affect the main process.

It looks like you're trying to create a slide show that shows one image every three seconds, and you want it to pause for an extra twenty seconds when somebody presses a key.  Is that right?

So, you've got one thread (the main thread) that runs the slide show, and you've got another that polls the keyboard, but your two threads don't communicate with one another.

You put a `time.sleep(20)` call in your keyboard thread.  But that only pauses the keyboard thread.  It doesn't do anything at all to the main thread.

What you need, is for the keyboard thread to set a variable that the main thread looks at after it wakes up from its three second sleep.  The main thread can look at the variable, and see if a longer sleep has been requested, and if so, sleep for twenty more seconds.

Of course, after the longer sleep, you will want the main thread to re-set the variable so that it won't *always* sleep for twenty seconds after the first time the keyboard is touched.

---

P.S.:  I am not a Python expert.  I know that in *other* programming environments (e.g., Java), you also have to worry about "memory visibility."  That is, when a variable is changed by one thread, there is no guarantee of when (if ever) some other thread will see the change...

...Unless, the threads use some kind of *synchronization* when they access the variable.

Based on what I have read (It's on the Internet!  It *must* be true!), Python either does not have that problem now, or it did not have that problem in the recent past.  I'm not sure which.

If memory consistency actually is an issue, then you will either have to use a [mutex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) when you access the shared variable, or else you will have to make the threads communicate through some kind of a synchronized object such as a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Comment: Yea, you hit the nail on the head with what I'm attempting. I going to try to set up a `flag` variable and see if I can communicate between the thread and main process.  If I want to use communicate this `flag` variable from my thread to the main thread, would I need to use global attribute within the function? I was told that thread and main thread share variables.

Comment: Use `global` exactly the same way you would use it anywhere else in Python code.  You did not need to declare `q` global in your `keyboard_press()` routine because `q` already was assigned at top-level before the `def keyboard_press()` happened.  But using `global` can't hurt, and it might help somebody else who was trying to read your program.